# Service for receiving file uploads (inverse CDN)

Tags: file-upload, upload

There are many services available for delivering content *to* users. I am looking for the reverse: a service for receiving content uploads *from* users.

Specifically, I'm building a web app where the files uploaded may be anywhere from 10MB to 100MB. I expect there are many issues around receiving this much data, and what I'm looking for is a service that handles those issues for me.

Comment: dropbox, box.net, amazon drive?

Comment: Do those have API's that make it easy to integrate with a web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Amazon S3 to receive uploads from users. You can generate a signed HTML form that will let your users upload files to a designated bucket; you can control the expiry of the form using a policy document.

[Amazon S3 Developer Guide: Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)

[Article: Browser Uploads to S3 using HTML POST Forms](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434)

As of April 2016, they also have a new feature called [Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html), which is closer in spirit to an actual "inverse CDN" for file uploads.

Answer (score 2):

[Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) is built to ease your pain of receiving, storing, processing and distributing files and images from your users. Give it a try, there's a [free](https://uploadcare.com/accounts/create/free) plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually solve this without paying a third party by using a HTML5/Flash uploader in your web app. I particularly recommend [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) (free, open-source). It's a javascript library that uses a choice of client frontends (HTML5, Flash, Silverlight, etc) to handle uploading the file(s) in a way that doesn't trigger browser timeouts and allows the user to see the progress of their uploads ([demo](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) with 10Mb limit).

Other than the script you only require a backend on the server to receive the data. You'll want to watch out for anything that could trigger a server-side timeout like PHP's MAX_FILE_SIZE or request timeouts.

The plupload package comes with example frontend and backend scripts so you should be up and running fairly quickly.

I've uploaded 80Mb files using plupload so I know it works. It's going to be slow on a typical DSL connection but no upload service is immune to that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) or [Google Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/). Both have dedicated API's and you only pay for the storage that you use. They both also have libraries avaliable in various languages to make integration easier.

Answer (score 0):

A couple other options:

https://www.yousendit.com/

http://www.uploadthingy.com/